# "Haar measures" on CGWH groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

Is there a suitable notion of "Haar measure" on CGWH groups (topological groups whose topology is compactly generated weak Hausdorff)? I know that if a topological group admits a Haar measure, then it should be locally compact. So a Haar measure does not exist in general CGWH groups. But what if we weaken the regularity properties? Does CGWH groups have a unique (up to scaling) translation invariant measure satisfying certain (weaker) regularities?

Comment: Well, there's always counting measure.  And in an example like $\mathbb{Q}$, there aren't any options other than counting measure (up to scaling).